# Recursively computing an N x N matrix determinant

Tags: f#

I'm having an issue with this implementation. It's giving me an error that "this expression to have type bool but here has unit" on the entire block starting at the first for loop and ending with the pown expression.

I'm not entirely sure what this means.

```
let rec detMat (m : int[,] ) : int = 
    let mutable det = 0
    let mutable n = m.Length
    let mutable i = 0
    let mutable j = 0
    let mutable j = 0
    let mutable j1 = 0
    let mutable j2 = 0
    let mTmp = Array2D.create 0

    if n  = 1 then
        det = m.[0, 0]
    elif n = 2 then
        det = m.[0, 0] * m.[1, 1] - m.[1, 0] * m.[0, 1]
    else
        det = 0
        for j1 = 0 to n do
            for i = 1 to n do
                j2 = 0
                for j = 0 to n do
                    if j <> j1 then
                        mTmp.[i-1, j2] <- m.[i, j]
                        j2 = j2 + 1
            pown -1 (1 + j1 + 1) * m.[0, j1] * detMat(mTmp, n-1)
    det
```

Comment: `=` is equality comparison, `<-` is assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<-` is the assignment operator for mutable variables.
Your code should be

`det <- m.[0, 0]`

`det <- m.[0, 0] * m.[1, 1] - m.[1, 0] * m.[0, 1]`

`j2 <- j2 + 1`

`=` is for equality, that's why you are getting the "this expression to have type bool" error. The second part, "but here has unit", means the compiler is expecting an arm of `if` to return a unit in the last expression. Carefully read this page to understand why the error message is so confusing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx